# Different versions of sqlite3 produce differently sized files

Tags: database, sqlite

This is just something I noticed and just very curious to understand why this was and if someone has a possible explanation for this behavior. 
I created 2 sqlite3 files, both with the exact same data. One was version 3.7.5 and on CentOS. The other one was on version 3.7.13 and on OSX. The resulting file had sizes of 16K and 28K, and page sizes of 1024 and 4096.

Does this have anything to do with default block sizes on the OSes or something else file-system related? Or nothing at all and this is because of some additional information that SQLite now stores in its files?

Comment: What is the output of `PRAGMA page_size;` for both files?

Comment: @CL: Ahh..there seems to be a difference. The page size for the 3.7.5 is 1024 and for 3.7.13 is 4096. This looks like a performance tuning parameter. Can you explain briefly what it is this parameter does to affect the size of the files and how it affects performance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newer SQLite versions do not store anything additional in database files (as long as you do not use new features).

All tables and indexes use their own pages, so the database file size is affected by the page size.
Each page has a fixed amount of overhead, so increasing the page size typcially increases performance by a little bit.
Changing the page size allows you to trade off speed against space requirements.

The default page size is affected by the actual block size of the storage device, and by how the OS reports it.